# jqGrid dynamically change from multigroup to single grouping

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

I'm working with jqGrid and have hit an issue that I can't quite identify...

I've got a grid setup with 2 level multi-grouping, and I've also got a select list to dynamically change the grouping. This all works well so far, and I can change the grouping appropriately based on the selected option. For example:

- Project 1

  - File 1

    - field 1, field 2, field 3
    - field 1, field 2, field 3
    - field 1, field 2, field 3
  - File 2

    - field 1, field 2, field 3
    - field 1, field 2, field 3
    - field 1, field 2, field 3
  - File 3

    - field 1, field 2, field 3
    - field 1, field 2, field 3
    - field 1, field 2, field 3
- Project 2

  - File 8

    - field 1, field 2, field 3
  - File 9

    - field 1, field 2, field 3

In this illustration, the project number is the output group and the file number is the inner group. Under each file group is a list of all of the rows in that group.

The issue is that I need an option to remove the inner grouping only and keep the outer grouping intact. I've tried the below code, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything:

```
 if (val == "clear")
 {
    failingRulesGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {
        groupingView:
        {
            groupField: ['ename'],
            groupOrder: ['asc']
        }
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

This is the code for dynamically changing the multi-grouping, and it is working perfectly:

```
if (val != "clear")
{
    failingRulesGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {
        groupingView:
        {
            groupField: ['ename', val],
            groupColumnShow: [false, false],
            groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc']
        }
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can remove the inner group but retain the output group? As a side note, the outer group will only ever be based on the 'ename' column so I don't need to worry about changing how the outer group is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't think of this before, but I've got a working solution. Using 'groupingGroupBy' solves this pretty easily:

```
if (val == "clear")
{
    gridSelector.jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', 'ename',
    {
    groupColumnShow: [false],
    groupCollapse: true
    });
}
```